# Forming partial differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I need to form a pde of the set of all spheres whose centers lie on the $x-$ axis.

For, $(x-a)^2+y^2+z^2=r^2\to (1),$  is an equation of the spheres whose center is at $x$ axis and radius $r.$

Here $a$ and $r$ are arbitrary constants, I need to eliminate $a$ and $r$ to form a pde of $(1)$.

If $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=p, \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=q,$ we have $(1)$ becomes $z^2(p^2+q^2+1)=r^2.\to (2) $

How to proceed further to eliminate $r$ from $(2).$

Comment: Why don't you start rescaling $x,y,z$ with $r$, i.e., $x\rightarrow x/r$, etc.?

Comment: What does it mean to "form a PDE of the set of all spheres?"

Comment: I don't think so that $r$ is arbitrary constant.

Comment: I think you need to rephrase the question. Spheres are geometrical objects, while the solutions to PDE's are functions. And the $z$-coordinate of a point on a sphere is not a function of $x$ and $y$ (it is not uniquely defined).

Comment: have you tried dividing (2) by r, so z'=z/r? i would put this as an answer, but it's a strange question...where's 'a' gone, and your p's and q's seem inverted at best...

Comment: I am not sure how you derived (2). It looks like you are differentiating something, but somehow $r^2$ is still there, and you have a sum of the squares of partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$? It looks like you got this wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to set it up as $x=x(y,z)$ (and as mentioned in the comments, this will not parametrize the whole sphere), then you can differentiate your equation (1) with respect to both variables and get
$$
2(x-a)x_y + 2y = 0 \quad\text{ and }\quad 2(x-a)x_z + 2z =0,
$$
using $x_y$ and $x_z$ for the partial derivatives. Dividing the equations by $2$ and multiplying by $x_z$ and $x_y$, respectively, you get
$$
(x-a)x_y x_z + y x_z = 0 \quad\text{ and }\quad (x-a) x_y x_z + z x_y =0,
$$
Now subtracting them gives
$$
yx_z - z x_y = 0
$$
which is the desired PDE.